# Protractor won't get repeater inside a ng-view

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, protractor

I've a tricky question for you guys out there. I've made a simple exercise webapp using AngularJS and `ngRoute`. 
Inside my `index.html` I got an `ng-view` element which provide two pages `search_page.html` and `detail_of_result_page.html`. The code works pretty fine, I put something in the first page input field, hit search button and all results magically appears in my page. The troubles comes with protractor that seems to not see my `result in results` repeater with his:

```
  element.all(by.repeater("result in results"))
```

I've tried to put in `browser.pause()` and watch for errors, but everything seems right.

I've forgot the error code from Protractor:

```
Failed: Index out of bound. 
Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator by.repeater("result in results")
```

Comment: it should work if you are doing it right, try to do ```browser.waitForAngular();``` or using ```ExpectedConditions``` with ```browser.wait()``` before getting your repeater. Suspect that you some how tried to get repeat before it is available. ---- P.S. some error output in terminal will be helpful for us to identify the problem ;)

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, I'll give it a try. The disgusting error code is: `Failed: Index out of bound. 
Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator by.repeater("result in results")`

Comment: Yes, it sounds exactly like the repeater is not ready to locate by protractor/selenium, or your ```$scope.results.length == 0``` at the time you try to locate it. Use either of my suggestion above will sure helped. ---- In case you can't figure it out. Then if you can provide some of your html or a screenshot of the view. I can give a helpful anser.

Comment: Nope, not working :'( If you have spare time, try to take a look. [link](https://github.com/carlfranz/myWebapp) row 32 of searchTest.js

Comment: Got you an answer, issue was about you click on the result list. And redirect to another route. Therefore your repeater doesn't available when ```beforeEach()``` run again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, under your `searchTest.js` `line: 27`

```js
    beforeEach(function () {

        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        browser.wait(EC.presenceOf($('li')),5000);

        var resultItem = element.all(by.repeater('result in results')).first(); //BUG

        var resultLink = resultItem.element(by.css('a'));
        resultLink.click();
        resultId = resultLink.getAttribute('href').then(function (attr) {
            //var res = attr.match('/\/TDDBook\/Search\/#\/detail\/(\d+)/')[1]; // TODO: fix this shit
            return 1;
        });
    });
```

Things seem alright until you do `resultLink.click();` Assuming that it work fine for the first `it ("should set the url to the selected detail view")`. But when it come to second `it("should see the details in the main page component")` at this moment you are no longer on `/#/splash` route. Therefore your pereater no longer available to be located when your `beforeEach()` run again.

## Solution

Your beforeEach doesn't seem useful and logically not run-able for your second `it("should see the details in the main page component")`. So just move all the thing like this:

```js
    it ("should set the url to the selected detail view",function () {
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        browser.wait(EC.presenceOf($('li')),5000);

        var resultItem = element.all(by.repeater('result in results')).first(); //BUG

        var resultLink = resultItem.element(by.css('a'));
        resultLink.click();
        resultId = resultLink.getAttribute('href').then(function (attr) {
            //var res = attr.match('/\/TDDBook\/Search\/#\/detail\/(\d+)/')[1]; // TODO: fix this shit
            return 1;
        });

        resultId.then(function (id) {
            var expectedUrl = '/detail/'+id;
            browser.getLocationAbsUrl().then(function (url) {
                expect(url).toBe(expectedUrl);
            })
        })
    })
```

**P.S.** just for your information, there is [Page Object](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/page-objects.md) in protractor, which will be fit with the thing you attempt to do with your `beforeEach()` . Plus with a tiny bit of knowledge of commonJS (`module.exports` & `require()`) it will perfectly suit your needs ;) Cheer!